# Basic JavaScript Question, Tic Tac Toe Game issue

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if you guys can help me with my issue. I have two:

One: Is it possible to make it more condensed? (See comment below)

Two: I'm pretty sure you have to make every possible winning combination in tic tac toe in the checkWin() function, but I don't know how to do that without putting *every* combination in it. See below, ***Note, I am using code.org AppLab, most lines of code do work, some may not***

```
var board = [];
var mode  = 0;
var turn  = 0;
var put;
var squareID;
var moveOn;
onEvent("playAloneBttn", "click", function() {
 setupGame();
 mode = 1;
});
//Is there a way to make this more efficient?
onEvent("slot1", "click", function() {
  squareID = 0;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot2", "click", function() {
  squareID = 1;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot3", "click", function() {
  squareID = 2;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot4", "click", function() {
  squareID = 3;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot5", "click", function() {
  squareID = 4;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot6", "click", function() {
  squareID = 5;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot7", "click", function() {
  squareID = 6;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot8", "click", function() {
  squareID = 7;
 updateSquare(); 
});
onEvent("slot9", "click", function() {
  squareID = 8;
 updateSquare(); 
});

function setupGame(){
  setScreen("game");
    turn = 1;
    board = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
}

function updateSquare(){
  if(turn == 1){put = 1} else {put = 2}
checkSquare();
if (moveOn == 1) 
{
  removeItem(board,squareID);
insertItem(board,squareID,put);
checkWin();
if (turn == 1){turn =2} else {turn = 1}
}
}
function checkSquare(){
  if (board[squareID]== 1 || board[squareID] == 2){
      moveOn = 0;
    }
    else {moveOn = 1}
}
function checkWin(){
///How do i do this?
}
```

Comment: It's time to learn about `for` loops. This code is 9x longer than it needs to be.

Comment: @tadman, I know what a for loop is, I didn't really know how to use it in this situation, mind elaborating?

Comment: Event delegation would greatly simplify the code. Instead of putting event listener on each square, you should consider creating a parent container for all squares and then putting a single event listener on that single element. You can use the `event` arg to determine the individual square that was clicked. Check out this great blog post for details: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i <=9; ++i) { onEvent("slot"+n, "click", () => { squareID = n - 1; updateSquare }) }` as an example.

Comment: I'd avoid the `for` and instead use a `data` property on the thing that gets clicked, or bind to a `.slot` selector and extract the number from the `id` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of how you can implement event delegation to make your code a lot simpler. You can see we only need to apply a single event handler to keep track of all button clicks, since the handler belongs to the parent container.

The remainder of the code just serves as a simple example of how you can update particular squares on `click` event:

```js
const handleClick = event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    const square = event.target;
    updateSquare(square);
  }
};

const updateSquare = square => {
  if (square.style.backgroundColor === 'red') {
    square.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  } else {
    square.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
};

document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: groove;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put a class on each slot, then iterate through the slots and create the onclick event.

```
var slots = document.getElementsByClassName("slot");
for(var x = 0; x < slots.length; x++){
   slots[x].onClick = function() {
        squareID = x; // why set the id when its clicked? doesnt make sense. should have an id weather clicked or not.
        updateSquare(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems good for HTML, I am using AppLab on code.org, so document.getElementsByClassName("slot"); comes up with an error, and it doesn't like functions within loops

Comment: Pretty sure you will need to declare `var x` as `let x` in this type of situation. Using `var` `x` will be the value of `slots.length - 1` every time `onClick` is called due to `var` being function scoped - `let`, on the other hand, is scoped to the for-loop block

Comment: I have found an answer Thanks